# Java Disable OSX Force Quit

Tags: java

How can I disable force quit from within my java application? Either that, or how about disabling it from .plist?

Comment: You ... want to stop the user from being able to exit your application? Why?

Comment: kiosk application. You dont want the user to be able to exit to the system. I want to intersect the force quit process so only a admin can quit

Comment: You don't want to be stopping the SIGKILL - you want to instead set up the kiosk so that the user is unable to access the Force Kill interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Using the .plist key "Application is agent (UIElement)" the application does not show up on the force quit list!

Comment: Which list are you talking about? The one you get with Command-Option-Esc? Surely, that process shows up in the Activity Monitor, doesn't it? As others have said you can't stop SIGKILL (but you might indeed be able prevent someone from sending it...)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot disable force-quit in an application. Force-Quit is equivalent to sending the SIGKILL signal. By definition:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  There is no way to handle SIGKILL, which will always terminate the application (Java or otherwise).