# How to use Apple's handleQuit method?

Tags: java, macos

I made a java application that saves data to a .data file. I have a Window Listener that listens for the application to close in order to fire the code to save the data to the file. When pressing the dedicated quit button I have, or pressing the red "X" on the window, everything is fine. However, when the user opts for the command + q route things go sour. The application is quit, but the data is not saved. How do I correctly implement apple's handleQuit(Application Event e) method to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want in that case is a [shutdown hook](http://www.developerfeed.com/threads/tutorial/understanding-java-shutdown-hook). A shutdown hook listens for the OS signal to close the app and is triggered when this signal is sent. A shutdown hook can run pretty much any code.

You can wire your built-in red "X" button to close the app (instead of saving the file), and the shutdown hook will catch the request and take care of saving the file.

The only caveat is that shutdown hooks are supposed to be made up of code that doesn't take very long to execute. So, the save of your file shouldn't take more than a second or two, and you shouldn't use confirmation dialog boxes that the user must acknowledge in a shutdown hook, because it can take an indefinite amount of time before the user recognizes the dialog.

The reason why shutdown hooks should be short lived is that when an application is requested to shutdown, the OS generally expects it to shutdown in a reasonable amount of time. If it doesn't, for example in Windows, the OS might display one of those, "Application isn't responding..." messages.

Finally, and you might run into this question later, you might wonder how to catch a "Force Quit" request from the Task Manager (or "Force Quit Applications" dialog on OS X). Well, you can't catch those, and you shouldn't try! While [it is possible to disable things like listing your app in the Force Quit menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145677/java-disable-osx-force-quit), this is a complete hack and should be avoided at all costs. If you're designing your app in a way that tries to circumvent options that should always be available to users and admins then that's a strong indication that your app is poorly designed, and/or a bad actor. Imagine if you installed an app that behaved in this way - wouldn't you think the programmer was being lazy or possibly malicious in trying to give their app un-killable qualities?

Also, force quitting is a forcible (ungraceful) shutdown that should only be used on applications when they are hung and won't quit normally. OSs need to have a force quit kind of option so that a user or admin has a way to kill a runaway or unresponsive app. If your users are force quitting your app they either misunderstand that force quitting isn't desirable, or there's something about the design of your app that makes force quitting more favorable than quitting your app normally. If this is the case (e.g. you hear from users that they force quit for one reason or another), it's usually an indication that portion of your app is poorly designed to match user's expectations.

Comment: As an aside, `java.util.Preferences` survive ⌘-Q. See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061318/230513).

Comment: That's a good reference, and it will work. However, it should be noted that hooking into this Apple-specific preference will cause your code to no longer be cross platform, if that matters.

Comment: Actually, that is important. It's used on both platforms and I wanted to keep it that way. So I must say, thank you for your answer. It was perfect.